# Moving average process notation: negative or positive $\theta$s?

Tags: notation, moving-average

I noticed that sometimes the moving average process is written in two different ways. I would like to know which one is correct.

$y_t = \epsilon_t + \theta \epsilon_{t-1}$

$y_t = \epsilon_t - \theta \epsilon_{t-1}$

Comment: This is a matter of notational conventions. You can see immediately that the model is the same for $\tilde\theta=-\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, where the first is, I would say, more common. They are equivalent because you can always transform $\theta$ to $-\theta$ and get the same process, with the same dynamics.

The variance is
\begin{eqnarray}
E(Y_t-\mu)^2&=&E(\epsilon_t+\theta\epsilon_{t-1})^2\notag\\
&=&E(\epsilon_t^2+2\epsilon_t\theta\epsilon_{t-1}+\theta^2\epsilon_{t-1}^2)\notag\\
&=&\sigma^2+0+\theta^2\sigma^2
\end{eqnarray}
and the first autocovariance is
\begin{eqnarray*}
E(Y_t-\mu)(Y_{t-1}-\mu)&=&E(\epsilon_t+\theta\epsilon_{t-1})(\epsilon_{t-1}+\theta\epsilon_{t-2})\\
&=&E(\epsilon_t\epsilon_{t-1}+\theta\epsilon_{t-1}^2+\theta\epsilon_t\epsilon_{t-2}+\theta^2\epsilon_{t-1}\epsilon_{t-2})\\
&=&0+\theta\sigma^2+0+0,
\end{eqnarray*} 
whether you define $\epsilon_t+\theta\epsilon_{t-1}$ or $\epsilon_t-(-\theta)\epsilon_{t-1}$.

Comment: You are of course correct, but spelling out the variance and autocovariance equations may be more of a distraction rather than a useful illustration, IMHO.

Comment: That is possible indeed. Maybe OP will weigh in.